# If you don't have direct access to the database, how would you see some rows in the table?

Tags: cognos

I'm sitting in on a training class and the instructor just asked the new hires a question I don't know the answer to myself. "If you don't have direct access to the database, how would you see some rows in the table through Cognos v9.5?"

Anybody have a solution?  I'm pretty new to Cognos still so please be specific!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to TM1? Could you be more specific about which cognos product your using?

Comment: Well sadly he didn't really specify.  But I believe in Framework Manager is where's saying.

Answer (score 0):

v 9.5 is TM1 only, there was no such Framework Manager release.

You can write custom SQL in TurboIntegrator using ODBC data source.

Comment: 'Don't have direct access to the database' implies you cannot use ODBC

Comment: 9.5 implies TM1, so it'll be either an ODBC connection or connection to a package published to Cognos Connection through framework. In hindsight, I think this was the proper answer: connecting to cognos package in TurboIntegrator ) http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v9r5m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.tm1_turb.9.5.2.doc/tm1_turb_id4171ConnectPubPackage_GV309.html

Comment: This might be one of those frequent cases where the instructor didn't know what he was talking about or the OP has misrepresented the question.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking BI (not TM1) then you would see rows through Cognos secured data sources. ie. the Cognos admininstrator creates a data source in Cognos (using Cognos Connection) which has access to the database. Then he grants you (as a Cognos user) access to the data source. You don't have direct access to the database but you have access to a Congos datasource via Cognos security, and you can see data that way.